# How can I prove this statement about isomorphism and inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to prove the following:

"Let T be an isomorphism of a vector space $V$. Prove that if $\langle u, v \rangle$ is an inner product of $V$, then the same happens with $P_{T} : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $P_{T} = \langle T(u), T(v) \rangle$."

I thought that using $T^{-1}(T(u)) = u$ could get me somewhere, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Asserting that $P_T$ is an inner product means that there is a sequence of properties that you have to check. With which ones of these properties are you having a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $P_T$ is conjugate symmetric because $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is conjugate symmetric. Also $\langle Tu,Tu \rangle=0\iff Tu=0\iff u=0$, because $T$ is an isomorphism. Note that $\langle Tcu,Tv \rangle=\langle cTu,Tv \rangle=c\langle Tu,Tv \rangle$ for every scalar $c$. Can you verify other properties?

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{V}$, then $T(\vec{u}) = A\vec{u}$ for some invertible matrix $A$. To check if $T(u) \cdot T(v)$ is a valid inner product, we must check three conditions: positive definiteness, symmetry, and linearity. We begin by noting that $T(\vec{u}) \cdot T(\vec{v}) = (A\vec{u}) \cdot (A\vec{v})$.

1. **Positive Definite**: $T(\vec{u}) \cdot T(\vec{u}) \geq 0$, with equality if and only if $\vec{u} = \vec{0}$. Because $T(\vec{u}) \cdot T(\vec{v}) = (A\vec{u}) \cdot (A\vec{u}) = \vec{v} \cdot\vec{v}$ for some $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and the original inner product was positive definite, we have $T(\vec{u}) \cdot T(\vec{v}) \geq 0$. To prove equality only occurs when $\vec{u} = \vec{0}$, we simply note that as $A$ is invertible, the only solution for which $A\vec{u} = \vec{0}$ is $\vec{u} = \vec{0}$. Again, as the original inner product was positive definite, we know that $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v} = \vec{0} \iff \vec{v} = \vec{0}$.
2. **Linearity**: $T(\vec{u}) \cdot T(\vec{w} + \vec{v}) = T(\vec{u}) \cdot T(\vec{w}) + T(\vec{u}) \cdot T(\vec{v})$. This can be rewritten as the condition $(A\vec{u}) \cdot (A(\vec{w} + \vec{v})) = (A\vec{u}) \cdot (A\vec{w} + A\vec{v})$, and applying the linearity of the original inner product, we have our result. Using similar logic, we can also verify that $T(k\vec{u}) \cdot T(\vec{v}) = k (T(\vec{u}) \cdot T(\vec{v}))$.
3. **Symmetry**: I'll assume your vector field is over the reals, although this is easy to verify for any other vector field with the concept of a conjugate. We require $T(\vec{u}) \cdot T(\vec{v}) = T(\vec{v}) \cdot T(\vec{u}) = \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}$, which is true because the original inner product was symmetric.